# Types of Foods mentioned in our religious texts

Tags: food

From Where can I read about Types of foods ( satvik, Rajvik and Tamsik) mentioned in our religious texts?

Answer (score 0):

Bhagavad Gita 17.7-10.:

> The food that people prefer is according to their dispositions. The same is true for the sacrifice, austerity, and charity they are inclined (or predisposed) toward. Now hear of the distinctions from Me. 7.
>
> Persons in the mode of goodness prefer foods that promote life span, and increase virtue, strength, health, happiness, and satisfaction. Such foods are juicy, succulent, nourishing, and naturally tasteful. 8.
>
> Foods that are too bitter, too sour, salty, very hot, pungent, dry, and full of chillies, are dear to persons in the mode of passion. Such foods produce pain, grief, and disease. 9.
>
> Foods that are overcooked, stale, putrid, polluted, and impure are dear to persons in the mode of ignorance. 10.

I hope this helps. Prd..